# BigDecimal code critique

Tags: java, android

I'm teaching myself BigDecimal and would appreciate a critique. In the code fragment below, I calculate a tip from user input: check and tip percentage (entered as integer):

```
 txt_check = txtcheck.getText().toString();
 tpercent = txttippct.getText().toString();

 BigDecimal hundred = new BigDecimal("100");
 BigDecimal pct = new BigDecimal(tpercent);

 BigDecimal bdpercent = pct.divide(hundred, 2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY); 
 BigDecimal bdcheck = new BigDecimal(txt_check);
 BigDecimal bdtip = new BigDecimal(txt_check);
 bdtip = bdtip.multiply(bdpercent);
 BigDecimal bdtotal = new BigDecimal(txt_check);
 bdtotal = bdtotal.add(bdtip);
```

The code above appears to function correctly. To display these values I convert to string:

```
 scheck = new DecimalFormat("####.00").format(bdcheck.doubleValue());
 scheck = StringUtils.leftPad(scheck,7," ");
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple calculation, the logic used for the `bdtip` and `bdtotal` variables wasnt straight forward. Instead of creating it with the value of one of the operands, then multiplying/adding it by the other operand, why not do something like the following:

```
txt_check = txtcheck.getText().toString();
tpercent = txttippct.getText().toString();

BigDecimal hundred = new BigDecimal("100");
BigDecimal pct = new BigDecimal(tpercent);

BigDecimal bdpercent = pct.divide(hundred, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY); 
BigDecimal bdcheck = new BigDecimal(txt_check);

BigDecimal bdtip = bdcheck.mulitply(bdpercent);
BigDecimal bdtotal = bdcheck.add(bdtip);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Following naming conventions makes the code easier to read. See *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*
2. `new BigDecimal("100")` could be a constant.
3. [`DecimalFormat.format(Object number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) accepts `BigDecimal` objects (without the necessity of converting it to `double` and loss of precision).